# Dúvida laço FOR em C

Tags: c

o codigo ta funcionando como eu preciso, minha duvida é por que o For nao deu errado? por exemplo, se o expoente for 3, ele ja nao vai ser maior que 1 e aí ja pararia o laço?
eu tava tentando fazer ele `for(expoente;expoente<=1;expoente--)` e nao tava dando certo(esse é o jeito que eu pensei que faria sentido). O codigo está abaixo. Ele calcula potenciaçao.

```
int main()
{

    float pot,base;
    int expoente;
    scanf("%f", &base);
    scanf("%d", &expoente);
    pot=base;

    for(expoente;expoente>1;expoente--)
    {
        pot=pot*base;
    }

    printf("%f", pot);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: É sempre bom atribuir um valor inicial à variável de controle do for de modo explícito, por.ex.: for (expoente=1; expoente<3; expoente++)

Answer (score 0):

Você está entendendo a condição do `for` ao contrário, como se fosse uma condição de parada, quando na verdade seria "de continuidade". Ou seja, a semântica é *execute o laço **enquanto** a expressão for verdadeira, e saia quando for falsa*.

Comment: Dúvida esclarecida. Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

O FOR continua enquanto a condição for verdadeira, e nao o contrario como acho que você está pensando... 
Obs: há dois problemas no seu código: expoente zero e expoente negativo. O velho e bom IF resolve facil....see you.